# How do I establish a trade route?

Tags: king-of-dragon-pass

I have recently picked up King of Dragon Pass, and I like exploring the strangeness of thin setting. Many of the things either make sense to me or I'm willing to try and figure them out, or I found some guidance online for the more mechanical things I'm less willing to try and try again, but I cannot figure out how to **establish a trade route**.

I have sent caravans with the goal of “establish trade route” to clans near and far, allied or owing favours or friendly, before and after building a shrine to Issaries, and yet no trade route was ever established.

What are the necessary conditions to establish a route? If they are met, how do I improve the chances that it actually happens?

Answer (score 1):

From the manual;

“Increase your ability to support trade routes by increasing the size of your Issaries shrine, spending magic on Sacred Time Trading rituals, increasing your population, and creating a tribe. Also, finding unusual raw materials on your lands will let your crafters make unique items which can boost your trading prowess.”

You didn’t mention the last (or an Issaries temple).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a specific trade (e.g. Goods for Cattle), choose the Establish Route radio button as the goal.

Comment: I have fixed the question. I did see and use that radio button, but I never had success establishing a route. That's why I'm asking for the conditions for it to work.

Comment: Ah, since the info was in the manual I thought there might be another issue.